# React получить содержание тега по клику

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Допустим, есть 2 дива, в первом текст `один`, во втором `два`.

Код следующий:

```
state = {
    clicked: false
}

tagClickHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({clicked: event.target.textContent})
    console.log(this.state.clicked)
}

<Tag
    clicked={this.tagClickHandler} 
/>
```

При клике **первый** раз на `один` в консоли вылетает `undefined` . При клике **второй** раз на `два`, в консоль вылетает `один`. Я понимаю логику, почему так, но как сделать так, чтобы при клике на любой тег, я получал содержимое именно кликнутого тега, а не предыдущего?

Answer (score 0):

Это связано с тем, что console вызван внутри функции, если выводить state **после** рендера компонента `Tag`, то все работает так, как надо.